# RTRIM from replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have used a replace statement to I have `@@@` after the name of the customer 
`MR@BOB@REED@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@`

I now want to get rid of the `@` after `reed`.

I tried:

```
select RTRIM(Name2,'@')
```

But I get the error

> The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: Have you used `replace` to replace all spaces with `@`? If so why? You could use `rtrim` on your string before you do that or...?

Comment: because the next bit of my code to seperate title, surname and forename uses the @s in the middle.

Comment: Why can't you use `rtrim` before your add `@` to your value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substring(Name2,0,charindex('@@',Name2)) from table
```

In above query, 'Name2' is the name of the column and table is the name of the 'table' containing that column.

Answer (score 2):

`RTRIM` removes trailing spaces.

You probably want `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING`

eg

```
select left('@mr@bob@reed@@@@@@@', charindex('@@','@mr@bob@reed@@@@@@@'))
```

Comment: There are a different amount of @s for different rows depending on how long the name is so how many spaces are left in the field

Comment: Then you need to use charindex to find two adjacent `@`s, and replace the 12 with the result of that function

Comment: Thanks but there is thousands of rows with diff names

Comment: this just returns empty fields